# Should I remove a LinkedIn contact who bullied me?

Tags: linkedin

I worked in a company and found some nice LinkedIn contacts. But there is a contact who started to bully me after a while. I think he can't stand me at all. Should I remove him to my LinkedIn contacts? Can this affect my possibilities to get a new job now as I'm unemployed?

Comment: is he/she a an-colleague?

Comment: Sorry. What is a an-colleague? English is not my native language.

Comment: It's ok, I'm a native English speaker and I don't know what an an-colleague is.

Comment: an 'ex-colleague', presumably

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Probably 90% of people won't even notice if you remove someone as a Linked-In contact. I surely wouldn't and I keep a pretty active profile.

Unless the company and this person are using Linked-In much, much, much more than average the person probably won't notice.

If they do use it that actively, you can [block them](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/47081/~/blocking-or-unblocking-a-member) completely.

Comment: That is true but I was thinking more about if some future employer asks him if I should be hired, will I lost the place because he thinks I'm not a good worker.

Comment: if you don't want to act as a reference for him, or don't trust him to act as a reference for you, he doesn't belong on your profile. Delete!

Comment: @jobless What makes you think he would have anything good to say even if you didn't remove him? If this person has bullied you in the past I doubt they would have a change of heart when asked about your possible performance.

Comment: I bet you could make that 99.99%. I am a fairly active user, and I never notice when someone removes *me* from their contacts. Paying attention to X removed Y is many galaxies away. :)

Comment: Thing is they won't notice it unless they only have a handful of connections.   Linkedin won't notify them of you dropping them, and they'll become a "follower" rather than a connection and still get your updates etc.

Answer (score 10):

What makes you think that keeping him as a contact is going to improve your chances with any prospective employer? A contact is valuable to you if you think that he could be helpful to you down the line. Do you think he will be helpful to you down the line? If he was bullying you, what are the chances he'll help you get a job? When was the last time that someone who bullied you helped you get a job? If you don't think he's going to be helpful, you know what you want to do to him as a contact.

Answer (score 5):

> Should I remove him to my LinkedIn contacts?

Yes, of course.  Don't keep contacts that you do not have a good relationship with.  LinkedIn is a professional social network.  Think of it this way... if you wouldn't want this person serving as a reference for you or vice versa, you don't have the intention of this ever being the case, and you don't intend to work with or do business with this person in the future, there is no reason to maintain the contact on LinkedIn.

> Can this affect my possibilities to get a new job now as I'm unemployed?

No, why would your future employer care who you are connected with on LinkedIn?  Unless that specific person is someone you want to work for (and they shouldn't be) then there isn't an issue.

Comment: I would argue that certain contacts, if they have a certain amazing reputation, can be a benefit to have on your contact list, because it might shine positively on you to have such a person's public acknowledgement of you. But I doubt that a bully would ever be such a person.

Comment: @Alec I couldn't disagree more.  When I'm looking to hire someone, I don't look at their list and say, "oh this person has a lot of high-value LinkedIn contacts, therefore they are desirable".  What I might do is contact a connection we have in common and ask questions.  Likewise, I wonder about those people with a large number of contacts.  Do they really have 1,300 meaningful connections?  Doubtful.  On my own profile, I only add people I know or want to know (that I then follow up with in-person).  That has served me very well, and I recommend others do the same.

Comment: @Alec I wouldn't be too surprised to find a bully to have an amazing reputation either.  In fact, a lot of the high powered business types have this dual reputation... someone who gets things done but at the expense of others.  Whether or not you can gel with these sorts of people varies on an individual basis.  In any case, someone truly bullying you cannot do you any good in your career.  Now, if this bully was really just providing some "tough love" or "harsh advice", that's a bit different.

Comment: I wasn't saying that anyone would judge a person based solely on their contact list. I was saying that IF a recruiter were to check a candidate's contact list, certain contacts might spark a "hey, have you ever worked with this person?"

Comment: As far as the probability of a bully being a desirable contact, I wouldn't spend much time thinking about it. It could go either way. I don't disagree with you.

Comment: @Alec Yes, agreed.

Comment: A bully is the type that would go after your lunch money. If you want lunch money, ask anyone but a bully.